# SWF ignore FacesMessage on evaluate transition redirect to next view without updating form

Tags: spring, jsf-2, groovy, primefaces, spring-webflow

On transition the flow redirect without rendering the FacesMessage in the current instance of the FacesContext (same issue with the MessageContext)
I checked the presence of FacesMessage in the FacesContext wich is correct but for a reason I dont touch the redirection is done even if the context contains messages inside

spring application context :

```
<faces:resources/>
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping"
      p:order="1"
      p:flowRegistry-ref="flowRegistry">
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <!--If no flow match, map path to a view to render; e.g. the "/home" path
        would map to the view named "home" -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="faceletsViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
      p:viewClass="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
      p:suffix=".xhtml"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter"
      p:flowExecutor-ref="flowExecutor"/>
<webflow-config:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow-config:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow-config:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        <webflow-config:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener"/>
        <webflow-config:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener"/>
    </webflow-config:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow-config:flow-executor>
<webflow-config:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
                              flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow-config:flow-location-pattern
            value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
</webflow-config:flow-registry>
<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices"
                             development="true"/>
<bean id="facesContextListener"
      class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>
<bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener"
      class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener"
      class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener"/>
```

controller :

```
@Named("registrationController")
class RegistrationController implements Serializable {

@Inject
@LangServiceQualifier
ILangService langService
@Inject
@RegistrationServiceQualifier
IRegistrationService registrationService

void validate(RegistrationModel model) {
    model.user.profile.lang ?: model.user.profile.setLang(registrationLang())
    try {
        registrationService.validate(model)
        model.header = new RequestHelper(request: FacesUtils.request).header
    } catch (RegistrationException re) {
        FacesContext context = FacesUtils.context
        re.messages.each {
            switch (it) {
                case new UsernameAlreadyExistsException().message:
                    context.addMessage("register_form_username_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: FacesUtils.bundle.getString(it)))
                    break
                case new PrimaryEmailAlreadyExistsException().message:
                    context.addMessage("register_form_currentEmailValue_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: FacesUtils.bundle.getString(it)))
                    break
                case new EmailRetypeException().message:
                    context.addMessage("register_form_currentEmailValueRetype_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: FacesUtils.bundle.getString(it)))
                    break
                case new PasswordRetypeException().message:
                    context.addMessage("register_form_password_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: FacesUtils.bundle.getString(it)))
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

spring web flow definition :

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="requestParameters.contains('from')?requestParameters.get('from'):'home'"
              result="flowScope.from"/>
    <evaluate expression="registrationService.initModel()"
              result="flowScope.model"/>
</on-start>

<view-state id="enterRegistration" model="model">
    <transition on="cancelRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction"/>
    <transition on="validateRegistrationAction" to="reviewRegistration">
        <evaluate expression="registrationController.validate(model)"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>

<view-state id="reviewRegistration" model="model">
    <transition on="cancelRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction"/>
    <transition on="reviseRegistrationAction" to="enterRegistration"/>
    <transition on="confirmRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction">
        <evaluate expression="registrationService.register(model)"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>

<end-state id="exitRegistrationAction" view="externalRedirect:#{from}"/>

<on-end>
    <evaluate expression="registrationController.clearRegistrationModel(flowScope.model)"/>
</on-end>
```

JSF page :

```
<h:form id="register_form">
                            <p:messages id="register_form_messages_id"/>
                                <p:outputLabel for="register_form_username_inputText_id"
                                               value="#{msgs['user.username.label']}"/>
                                <p:inputText id="register_form_username_inputText_id"                                            
                                             label="#{msgs['user.username.label']}"
                                             value="#{model.username}"/>
                                <p:outputLabel for="register_form_currentEmailValue_inputText_id"
                                               value="#{msgs['user.currentEmailValue.label']}"/>
                                <p:inputText id="register_form_currentEmailValue_inputText_id"
                                             label="#{msgs['user.currentEmailValue.label']}"
                                             value="#{model.email}"/>
                                <p:outputLabel
                                    for="register_form_currentEmailValueRetype_inputText_id"
                                    value="#{msgs['user.currentEmailValueRetype.label']}"/>
                                <p:inputText
                                    id="register_form_currentEmailValueRetype_inputText_id"
                                    label="#{msgs['user.currentEmailValueRetype.label']}"
                                    value="#{model.emailRetype}"/>
                                <p:outputLabel for="register_form_password_inputText_id"
                                               value="#{msgs['user.password.label']}"/>
                                <p:password id="register_form_password_inputText_id"
                                            label="#{msgs['user.password.label']}"
                                            value="#{model.password}"/>
                                <p:outputLabel for="register_form_passwordRetype_inputText_id"
                                               value="#{msgs['user.passwordRetype.label']}"/>
                                <p:password id="register_form_passwordRetype_inputText_id"
                                            label="#{msgs['user.passwordRetype.label']}"
                                            value="#{model.passwordRetype}"/>
                                <p:commandButton
                                    id="exit_registration_cmd_btn_id"
                                    action="cancelRegistrationAction"
                                    value="#{msgs['cancel.button']}"
                                    immediate="true"/>


                                <p:commandButton
                                    id="validate_registration_cmd_btn_id"
                                    action="validateRegistrationAction"
                                    value="#{msgs['register.label']}"
                                    update="@form"
                                    ajax="false"/>
                    </h:form>
```

I'm running under openjdk7 tomcat7 mojarra primefaces and the issue is the same with glassfish 3.1.2, groovy 2.0.5 with groovy eclipse compiler, spring 3.2, spring webflow 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a workaround, but still dont know what "court-circuite" the JSF lifecycle to not let the message be displayed inside an evaluate of a transition, so I had to use a decision-state to block the transition and change the controller method signature, and made the validation process return a boolean to indicate the environment the weather of the validation and that way force to stay on this view with the same populated request map.

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Named
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@Named("registrationController")
class RegistrationController {

static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController)

Logger getLog() { return log }

@Inject
@LangServiceQualifier
ILangService langService
@Inject
@RegistrationServiceQualifier
IRegistrationService registrationService


Lang registrationLang() {
    return langService.supportedLangs.find {
        it.code == FacesContext
                .currentInstance
                .externalContext
                .requestLocale
                .language
    } as Lang ?: langService.defaultLang
}

Boolean validateModel(RegistrationModel registrationModel) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.currentInstance
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            II18nConfigService.BUNDLE_BASE_NAME_VALUE,
            context.viewRoot.locale,
            Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
    registrationModel.user.profile.lang ?: registrationModel.user.profile.setLang(registrationLang())
    try {
        registrationService.validate(registrationModel)
        registrationModel.header = new RequestHelper(
                request: context
                        .externalContext
                        .request as HttpServletRequest).header
    } catch (RegistrationException re) {
        assert !re.messages.empty
        re.messages.each {
            switch (it) {
                case new UsernameAlreadyExistsException().message:
                    context.addMessage "register_form_username_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: bundle.getString(it))
                    break
                case new PrimaryEmailAlreadyExistsException().message:
                    context.addMessage "register_form_currentEmailValue_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: bundle.getString(it))
                    break
                case new EmailRetypeException().message:
                    context.addMessage "register_form_currentEmailValueRetype_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: bundle.getString(it))
                    break
                case new PasswordRetypeException().message:
                    context.addMessage "register_form_password_inputText_id",
                            new FacesMessage(
                                    severity: FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                    summary: bundle.getString(it))
                    break
            }
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE
}
}
```

flow definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
<on-start>
    <evaluate expression="requestParameters.contains('from')?requestParameters.get('from'):'home'"
              result="flowScope.from"/>
    <evaluate expression="registrationService.initModel()"
              result="flowScope.registrationModel"/>
</on-start>

<view-state id="enterRegistration" model="registrationModel">
    <transition on="validateRegistrationAction" to="isValidModelDecision">
        <evaluate expression="registrationController.validateModel(registrationModel)"
                  result="flowScope.isValidModel"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancelRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction" history="discard"/>
</view-state>

<decision-state id="isValidModelDecision">
    <if test="isValidModel" then="reviewRegistration" else="enterRegistration"/>
</decision-state>

<view-state id="reviewRegistration" model="registrationModel">
    <transition on="reviseRegistrationAction" to="enterRegistration"/>
    <transition on="confirmRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction">
        <evaluate expression="registrationService.register(registrationModel)" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancelRegistrationAction" to="exitRegistrationAction"     history="discard"/>
</view-state>

<end-state id="exitRegistrationAction" view="externalRedirect:#{from}"/>
</flow>
```

It's only a workaround not an explainantion of what is wrong with my code, just my hack to continue.

Comment: Finally I found that the comportement who lets the transition happen even if there was messages in the faces context was the evaluate balise who needs to be feeded with an expression returning a boolean value.